# Downloading data from all users with Graph API

Tags: graph

Is it possible to download data from all Facebook users (not only your own friends) using the Graph API? Is it for instance possible to get demographics from all users in a city?

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding we can not retrieve information of users in city directly using graph API.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for you answer Nilesh!

Comment: As far as user list concerned you can get friend list of any user using endpoint, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/